# How to add a level to a dataframe in pandas where the new level comes from a column of another dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe that I have named as `data_df`, Which looks like this.

```
        A             B             C               D
    a1 a2  a3     b1 b2 b3      c1 c2 c3        d1 d2 d3
1   1   2   3     5   6  7      3  4   5        10  1  8
2   0   5   4     8   7  9      1  5   7        8   6  1
```

I have another dataframe named `universe_df` which looks like this

```
Index Symbol Category
1       A       X
2       B       Y
3       C       Y
4       D       Z
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
       X                     Y                    Z
       A               B           C              D
    a1 a2  a3       b1 b2 b3    c1 c2 c3       d1 d2 d3
1   1  2   3         5  6  7     3 4   5        10 1  8
2   0  5   4         8  7  9     1  5  7         8 6  1
```

How should I go about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not really on external resources for the core of the question. Craft a minimal example and provide the code directly in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to figure out how to do that. Still couldn't get the columns to align, hope this is legible.

Comment: Can you make a **minimal** example? 2/3 cols, 3/4 rows of dummy data is probably more than enough to illustrate what you want. And provide the matching expected output.

Comment: *NB. Text between triple backticks (`\`\`\`data\`\`\``) is much easier to use than markdown tables.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made the edits, I hope the question makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'a1'): {1: 1, 2: 0}, ('A', 'a2'): {1: 2, 2: 5}, ('A', 'a3'): {1: 3, 2: 4}, ('B', 'b1'): {1: 5, 2: 8}, ('B', 'b2'): {1: 6, 2: 7}, ('B', 'b3'): {1: 7, 2: 9}, ('C', 'c1'): {1: 3, 2: 1}, ('C', 'c2'): {1: 4, 2: 5}, ('C', 'c3'): {1: 5, 2: 7}, ('D', 'd1'): {1: 10, 2: 8}, ('D', 'd2'): {1: 1, 2: 6}, ('D', 'd3'): {1: 8, 2: 1}})
print (data_df)
   A        B        C         D      
  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3  d1 d2 d3
1  1  2  3  5  6  7  3  4  5  10  1  8
2  0  5  4  8  7  9  1  5  7   8  6  1


universe_df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'}, 'Category': {1: 'X', 2: 'Y', 3: 'Y', 4: 'Z'}})
print (universe_df)
  Symbol Category
1      A        X
2      B        Y
3      C        Y
4      D        Z
```

First check if same ouput, no trailing whitespaces:

```
print (universe_df)
MultiIndex([('A', 'a1'),
            ('A', 'a2'),
            ('A', 'a3'),
            ('B', 'b1'),
            ('B', 'b2'),
            ('B', 'b3'),
            ('C', 'c1'),
            ('C', 'c2'),
            ('C', 'c3'),
            ('D', 'd1'),
            ('D', 'd2'),
            ('D', 'd3')],
           )

print (universe_df['Symbol'].tolist())
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Create `Series` for mapping first level in list comprehension and recreate MultiIndex:

```
d = universe_df.set_index('Symbol')['Category']

data_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d.get(a), a, b) for a, b in data_df.columns])
print (data_df)
   X        Y                  Z      
   A        B        C         D      
  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3  d1 d2 d3
1  1  2  3  5  6  7  3  4  5  10  1  8
2  0  5  4  8  7  9  1  5  7   8  6  1
```

Or you can mapping first level of MultiIndex:

```
d = universe_df.set_index('Symbol')['Category']

a = data_df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = data_df.columns.get_level_values(1)

data_df.columns = [a.map(d),a, b]
```

Another idea with helper DataFrame:

```
d = universe_df.set_index('Symbol')['Category']

df = data_df.columns.to_frame()
df.insert(0, '', df[0].map(d))

data_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
print (data_df)
   X        Y                  Z      
0  A        B        C         D      
1 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3  d1 d2 d3
1  1  2  3  5  6  7  3  4  5  10  1  8
2  0  5  4  8  7  9  1  5  7   8  6  1
```

Comment: It's not working, The topmost level is becoming Nan

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee - what is `a = data_df.columns.get_level_values(0)` `print (a)`

Comment: It's ````Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
              ...
              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
             dtype='float64', length=1488)````

Comment: That's after running the code you provided

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee - because not matched data, so ask for `a = data_df.columns.get_level_values(0) print (a)` and also `d = universe_df.set_index('Symbol')['Category']
, print (d)`

Comment: Before running your code a is ```` Index([A  A  A  A  B B B B C C C C D D D D] )````

Comment: d is a dataframe with symbol as the index and category as the column

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee - Can you check `EDIT` part in my answer? Do you have same output?

Comment: For the helper DataFrame too the topmost level is still Nan

Comment: Is it okay if I shared the colab notebook with you in chat?

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee - Better is add to your question by edit what is `print (universe_df)` and `print (universe_df['Symbol'].tolist())`

Comment: These print functions are generating the correct outputs. The first one is showing the universe_df dataframe and the second one is showing the symbols in a list

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee - added data to answer, for me working all solutions perfectly.

Comment: It's working with the dummy dataframes but strangely not with the ones that I am actually working